# Does an orientable subbundle of an orientable vector bundle always have a orientable complement?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

If I have an orientable vector bundle $E$ and a subbundle $F$ on a manifold $M$, where both the bundles are orientable, does $F$ have a complement in $E$ which is also orientable? Does it have a complement bundle at all? That is, a subbundle of $E$ that is pointwise a complement of $F$.

What if $F$ is of codimension $1$? Is the complement always trivial in this case?

Does anything change if $E$ is specifically the tangent bundle $TM$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $E=F\oplus G$, then $\Lambda^\det E=\Lambda^\det F\otimes\Lambda^\det G$. If both $\Lambda^\det E$ and $\Lambda^\det G$ are trivial, then so is $\Lambda^\det F$, because the three being line bundles, you can «divide by $\Lambda^\det G$» in that equality.

Comment: By $\Lambda^\det$ I mean the maximal exterior power here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this by the fact that any sub bundle has a complement (choose a metric and take the orthogonal complement) and now use that a bundle is orientable iff its first stiefel-whitney class vanishes and that this class is additive under direct sums.